# How to read and store a 64-bit UNSIGNED long from a ByteBuffer in Java? Where to store it, since long can't hold it?

Tags: java, biginteger

My understanding is that Java MAX_LONG is 9223372036854775807 but that's because it is signed. An **unsigned** 64-bit number can be much bigger than that. I suspect I have to use a BigInteger, but how do I go from BigInteger to 64-bit unsigned and back?

> What exactly do you mean by going from BigInteger to 64-bit unsigned and back?

I have a 64-bit unsigned number arriving in a big-endian ByteBuffer. Let's say it is Long.MAX_VALUE + 1 or 9223372036854775808. I can't store this on a long, so it has to go inside a BigInteger. Then I have to do the opposite. I have a 64-bit unsigned number in a BigInteger and I have to write to the ByteBuffer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by going from BigInteger to 64-bit unsigned and back?

Comment: By the way you can store 64 bits in a long. The signedness doesn't matter much, you just need to be careful when for example comparing (see `Long.compareUnsigned`) or dividing it. If you want the BigInteger anyway, it is easy to go through a long first too.

Comment: @harold That's true. But how do I print 9223372036854775808 to System.out?

Comment: Well there is also `Long.toUnsignedString`

Comment: @EddieBravo Is the problem that you don't know how to get the number from the ByteBuffer to the BigInteger or how to get the number from the BigInteger to the ByteBuffer? What have you tried so far? What is the current code you have? What is the problem you get?